# Lost documents, missing home directory

Tags: boot, files, directory, home-directory

I need my files for school. I seemed to have lost my home directory. Is it hidden? or did it get dumped? How do I get my document files back from my hard drive

My OS only boots up into the log in screen. I am able to access terminal through CTRL/ALT F2, but if I try to boot into GUI it crashes and boots back into the log in screen.

I tried to boot Ubuntu live, but could not find my /home directory in the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Enter into the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2, login to the terminal, and type `cd /home/[userhere]/`.
If the home directory exists it should cd into that directory. If it complains about there being no such directory, then you'll have to try and find it elsewhere (try using `cd /` then `dir`).